# Deletion of categories but not items on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

is there a way I can delete all the categories and subcategories on my wordpress website but not the items, so that I'm able to place the items in new categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are free to delete categories and subcategories from wordpress under the tab **categories** this process will not delete the products(items) for sure.